# How to slide down to show content of DIV using CSS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a slide down button to show the content of a `DIV` that has no height. I did an example here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjebR/)

I looked for this special form of sliding buttons but all I have found were examples where a `DIV` and its content has given width and height.

In my example the structure is different to that but it is quiet simple. There are three different divisions. A head with given height, the content div (depends from padding) that should be shown and below that the slider/trigger (also with given height) as a button.

Now I would like click on the trigger that slides down about the height of the content div and finally the content div should be appear.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You know that your fiddle has not jQuery loaded right?

Comment: What LightStyle said -- http://jsfiddle.net/qjebR/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking at.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6WrV/)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').hide(); //hide initialy
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // target only the content which is a sibling
        $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle(200, function () {
            $this.text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'click to close' : 'click to open');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i forgot to mention that the start position should be closed. and what in case if there are more than one of class slide and toggle? thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead (it also helps when jQuery is loaded, but that was probably just an oversight when you made it):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('.content').slideToggle(500, function () {
            $this = $(this);
            $slide = $('.slide');
            if ($this.is(':visible')) {
                $slide.text('Click to close');
            } else {
                $slide.text('Click to open');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/Ujnkp/2/)

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i forgot to mention that the start position should be closed. and what in case if there are more than one of class slide and toggle? thanks alot.

Comment: You should use `prev` instead that way you capture elements before the slideToggler